# Nested SQL statements Getting error. Three tables select

Tags: sql

I don't know if I am over complicating things or what but my SQL code gives errors. I am trying to find all the 'pid' that match from table parts.

Below is the necessary info.

Table: `Parts`:

```
pid, Color
```

Table: `Supplier`

```
sid
```

Table: `Catalog`

```
pid, sid
```

I am trying to retrieve the `pid` which have Color Red and a Supplier i.e exist in `sid` of table `Supplier`.

Here is my so far attempt:

```
SELECT pid 
FROM catalog 
WHERE sid = (SELECT sid 
             FROM 'suppliers' 
             WHERE sid=)(SELECT sid 
                         FROM `catalog` 
                         WHERE pid=)(SELECT pid 
                                     FROM `parts` 
                                     WHERE color = 'Red')
```

My 2nd Attempt says error, subquery returns more than 1 row:

```
SELECT pid FROM catalog c where c.pid=(SELECT pid from parts p where p.color='Red') AND c.sid=(SELECT sid FROM suppliers s)
```

Comment: Kind of a weird way to do it, but should still probably work if you pull the single quotes out from around the table names (after the FROMs).  Some kind of JOIN solution would be standard here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use two simple `INNER JOIN`'s instead of those nested subqueries?

```
SELECT c.pid 
FROM catalog  c
INNER JOIN suppliers s ON c.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN parts p ON c.pid = p.pid
WHERE p.color = 'Red'
```

Comment: is there no way to just do this using AND?

Comment: @user2997307: using `INNER JOIN` is the simplest and most effective way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misplacing the open paranthesis. But I'd recommend using JOIN query instead.

```
SELECT pid 
FROM Catalog C
INNER JOIN suppliers S ON C.sid = S.sid
INNER JOIN parts P ON C.pid = P.pid
WHERE P.color = 'Red'
AND S.sid = 'your_requirement'
```

Comment: If you mention `JOIN` why don't you use `JOIN`? Your syntax is outdated and should not be used because it can lead to errors. So try 'select c.pid from catalog c join supplier s on c.sid=s.sid join parts p on c.pid = p.pid where p.color = 'Red'

Comment: @alzaimar I'm sorry. This is how I actually did it. I'll change it. Thanks.

Comment: Guys, is there no way to just do this using AND?

Comment: @user2997307 I'm not sure what you're trying to ask but this would be the recommended way of getting the result you want

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid inner queries as suggested by @ncdreamy and use JOINS instead.

```
SELECT pid 
FROM catalog AS c 
INNER JOIN Parts AS p ON p.pid = c.pid 
INNER JOIN suppliers AS s on s.sid = c.sid
WHERE p.color = 'RED'
```